# Why does overriding __lt__ also change the greater-than operation? Why use it to sort?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing leetcode (https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/)
and I found the solution in leetcode is :

```
class LargerNumKey(str):
    def __lt__(x, y):
        return x+y > y+x

class Solution:    
    def largestNumber(self, nums: List[int]) -> str:
        largest_num = ''.join(sorted(map(str, nums), key=LargerNumKey))
        return '0' if largest_num[0] == '0' else largest_num
```

I am not sure about why here it overrides `__lt__` in LargerNumKey. Why not override `__gt__`?
And why does the condition in `__lt__` use `x+y > y+x`?

Comment: Make sure your questions are self-contained. *And why does the condition in `__lt__` use `x+y > y+x`?* currently can't be answered without referring to the leetcode question or guessing at its contents.

Answer (score 2):

> I am not sure about why here it overrides `__lt__` in LargerNumKey. Why not override `__gt__`?

according to [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) `sorted` does use `__lt__` for sorting,

> The sort routines are guaranteed to use `__lt__()` when making comparisons between two objects.